# Combine multiple input buttons across several pages into a single button on a single html page

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

first post here.

I have been asked to combine 3 pages which each have a submit button into a single page (as the last 2 pages have no options to choose from thus have little value).

The code looks like:

Registration form:

```
<input id="self_reg_btn" onclick="validateSelfReg();" style="clear: both;" type="button" value="Register" /></form>
```

Validation/Verification option:

```
<input id="email_verification" onclick="mailVerifySelected();" type="button" value="Verify Email" /></div>
```

Send me confirmation:

```
<input id="close_verify" onclick="closeVerifyPage();" type="button" value="Close" />
```

In essence, I want to execute the three onClick actions within a single page by clicking on a single button. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Of course. Just add a new button and execute the three functions.

```js
function a(){
   console.log("a");
}

function b(){
   console.log("b");
}

function c(){
   console.log("c");
}
```

```html
<input id="myButton" onclick="a(); b(); c();" type="button" value="Click me" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. And the different IDs will not matter? I will try it and revert.

Comment: @MannySolo it doesnt matter. As you can see we set aside the 3 buttons and just called the function those buttons call too.

Comment: Thank you Abana Clara and Rikard for your help.

Comment: @MannySolo you should pick an answer between me or rikard

Answer (score 1):

Calling all methods in onclick is one way, another way is to create a new function that runs alla tree functions, which makes it easier to read.

```
function validate() {
    validateSelfReg();
    mailVerifySelected();
    closeVerifyPage();
}
```

And then just call that function

```
<input id="btn-verify" onclick="validate();" type="button" value="Verify" />
```